# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'name' of 'QuestionTwoScreen.QuestionTwoScreen(string, int)'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Here is the error which I have encountered:

```
private void ShowNextQuestion()
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        Hide();
        new QuestionTwoScreen().Show();
    }
```

The error is the `new QuestionTwoScreen().show();`
Error   CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'name' of 'QuestionTwoScreen.QuestionTwoScreen(string, int)'

I think that I have not done this part right:

```
public QuestionOneScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CenterToScreen();
        AllowDropping();
        ScoreLbl.Text = "Score: " + StartScreen.Player.Score;
        SetupTimer();
    }
```

I think that because I have on the QuestionTwoScreen this:

```
public QuestionTwoScreen(string name, int quizSelection)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CenterToScreen();
        ScoreLbl.Text = "Score: " + StartScreen.Player.Score;
        SetupQuiz(name,quizSelection);
    }
```

I cannot see where I went wrong however I know that the 'QuestionOneScreen' doesn't have the (string, int). Is this why there is an error or is it something else?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: Yes, you created a constructor that requires 2 parameters and are not supplying them.

Comment: Well I dont understand what it means but I know that there is something missing which I think is why im getting the error

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: Do I need to add the `string name, int questionSelection` to the QuestionOneScreen?

Comment: I don't understand the "required formal parameter 'name' ".

Comment: @SLaks is the basically saying that it is needed for the parameter to work?

Comment: I'm saying that if your function / ctor wants parameters, you have to give it parameters.

Comment: `required formal parameter 'name'` means that your ctor declared a parameter called `name` which is required.

Comment: ahh ok. Thanks for helping me understand better @SLaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "QuestionTwoScreen" class constructor requires two objects (string name, int quizSelection) to be given to it each time it is created/instantiated.  The error that getting is being thrown because you are not passing in either value when constructing the class.  To fix this problem you can do two things:

Add in values for the missing parameters

```
new QuestionTwoScreen("Example Name", 0/*Example Int*/).Show();
```

Add default values to the parameters

```
public QuestionTwoScreen(string name = String.Empty, int quizSelection = 0)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CenterToScreen();
        ScoreLbl.Text = "Score: " + StartScreen.Player.Score;
        SetupQuiz(name,quizSelection);
    }
```

Comment: @FSCockers Sure thing.  Do you think you understand why it was throwing the error now?  If not, tell me what you're thinking the problem was and I'll fill in any gaps.

Comment: i do understand where i went wrong. I didn't add the two parameters which i have added when calling the different methods. Thanks for the help.